# PHP IS_DIR Condition Not Working In Loop With Continue

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, continue, scandir

I know this is a dummy question.
But I have banging my head more than an hour to make it works.

```
$path = '/dir/path';
$files = scandir($path);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (($file === '.' || $file === '..') || (is_dir($file))) continue;
    if (empty($file)) {
        echo $file.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Suppose I just want to show empty files within a directory than also content subdirectories.

How to make the `is_dir` condition works with `continue` statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `empty()` is probably the wrong thing here - you may want [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)

Comment: @NigelRen How to use it to exclude the subdirectories? I still can not figure it out.  Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to check for `.` and `..` separately. `is_dir()` can handle those too.

Comment: @simon I figured it out. I forget to make it full path,  `is_dir($path.'/'.$file)` solved it. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little typo remind me to start printing or echoing when a problem begin to show up. 
By that I can find the solution faster.

The typo `is_dir` need full path to be executed, so the right code is `is_dir($path.'/'.$file)`.

```
$path = '/dir/path';
$files = scandir($path);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (($file === '.' || $file === '..') || is_dir($path.'/'.$file)) continue;
    if (empty($file)) {
        echo $file.'<br>';
    }
}
```